# Ansible network module with multiple hosts in the provider

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to use a network module i.e. **ios_config** with multiple hosts in the **provider**

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    cli:
      host: 
        - 192.168.1.222
        - 192.168.1.200
      username: admin
      password: PASS1
      authorize: yes
      auth_pass: PASS2

  tasks:
    - name: Do something
      ios_config:
        lines:
          - ntp logging
          - ntp source Vlan900
        provider: "{{cli}}"
```

Ideally I would like to be able to iterate over multiple hosts.

I did try the `hosts: "{{vars['groups']['my_group']}}"` and using just a list as in the main example, but I wasn't lucky.

Can it be done?

Comment: Open [module's doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ios_config_module.html); find the argument in question; read. No mention of a list? No, you can't. Use a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use templated provider variable and leverage Ansible's host loop mechanism:

hosts:

```
[devices]
192.168.1.222
192.168.1.200
```

playbook:

```
- hosts: devices
  connection: local
  vars:
    cli:
      host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      username: admin
      password: PASS1
      authorize: yes
      auth_pass: PASS2

  tasks:
    - name: Do something
      ios_config:
        lines:
          - ntp logging
          - ntp source Vlan900
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
```

I added `connection: local` to force Ansible do everything from localhost (as required by network modules) and used `host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"` inside a `cli` variable.

Comment: Is there a different way of looping through the hosts without using the inventory?, the issue I have is that using the inventory will push me out side of tower licence :(

Comment: @techraf sorry... but I can't see the solution, do you mind pointing it out please.